# Why does the text is only clickable once then stops working?

Tags: javascript

I have a username that works perfectly on the first click. However, the second click stops working and won't do anything. Do you have any thoughts as to why that is?

```
var $username = $('<span class="username" data-value="' + message.user + '"></span>');
$username.text('@' + message.user + ': ');

$(".username").click(function(){

 var username = $(this).data("value");
 var userIndex = users[username].length - 1;

 while(userIndex >= 0) {  
  console.log('hello', username)
  userIndex -= 1;
 }
});
```

Comment: try `$(".username").on('click', function(){`

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: First, make sure the click handler is actually invoked when you click the second time by adding a `console.log` at the beginning of the function.  If it is invoked, it must be the following code that causes problem.

Answer (score 0):

try `$(".username").toggle(function(){`
here you can see on jquery docs about toggle event [Jquery toggle() event](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, once you click the button, the whole function is executed, i.e., the while loop executes completely until the condition becomes false, so all the iterations gets completed on one click and the when you click again it's not working...

Try this solution:

Instead of while loop, use forEach and put the click event inside the forEach function, so for every iteration, you can click again and again to get the result till the last element.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating how I would use forEach in this case? Sorry a bit of confused here...

Comment: forEach iterates through every element in the array and for each element it iterate it does some function which you define..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

You can even use for loop like for(i=0;i<n;i--), instead of forEach
and inside for loop, mention the click event

Comment: Just try placing the click event inside the loop and try